# Differences between "Join a Domain or Workgroup wizard" and making changing the proptery

Tags: windows, networking

I was wondering what the difference is between joining a domain with the "Network-ID" wizard or doing it manually by changing the propterty to domain.
Is the wizard doing some additional changes?
I couldn't find any specific information about it.

Thanks, Chaosbit

Answer (score 0):

The wizard gives you extra steps to walk some through if they need to add to a domain or not, in the end should accomplish the same task.